# Not able to bind data in modal, ModalInstance.result.then always getting dismissed

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of records. In each record, I have a Edit button. Clicking on edit button will open a modal where the current data needs to be bound.

However, when I click on Edit, an empty modal always opens without data filled in. On debugging, I came to know that the due to some problem, the control is going to the error part, so I am constantly getting a message showing "the modal is getting dismissed".

Following is my code:

```
var EditModalInstance = $modal.open({
   templateUrl: "EditCourseModal.html",
   controller: EditModalInstanceCtrl,
   resolve: {
       courseDetails: function () {
          return $scope.courseDetails;
       }
   }
});

EditModalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
   $scope.selected = selectedItem;
   $log.info(selectedItem + "Here I am.");
}, function () {
   $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date()); //control is coming in this part always
});
```

And here is my controller for modal:

```
var EditModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, coursesFactory,
courseDetails)              {

$scope.courseDetails = courseDetails;
$scope.selected = $scope.courseDetails;

$scope.update = function () {
    coursesFactory.updateCourse($scope.courseDetails)
    .success(function (status) {
        $scope.status = "Course details updated.";
        $log.info(status);
        getCourses();
    })
    .error(function (error, status) {
        $scope.status = "Unable to update course details.";
        $log.warn(error, status);
    });
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('close');
};
};
```

Then I have used this courseDetails in the view as:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="EditCourseModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <span><strong>Edit course</strong></span>
       <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="cancel()">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <dl>
         <dt>Id</dt>
         <dd><span>{{courseDetails.Id}}</span></dd>
       </dl>
       <dl>
         <dt>Name</dt>
         <dd>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="courseDetails.Name"></input>
         </dd>
       </dl>
       <dl>
         <dt>Duration</dt>
         <dd>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="courseDetails.Duration"></input></dd>
         </dl>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="update()">Update</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
     </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The error callback takes an argument. Provide an argument to `function (error) {
   $log.info('Modal dismissed because:" + error); `. Then check if there are some details available.

Comment: @Chandermani  No. I think I was mistaken while debugging. It's neither going to error part nor success part. I am not getting what is happening. When I try to dismiss the modal then it's working. But I am constantly getting [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress as error while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that your resolve is not a promise object i.e. $scope.courseDetails; is perhaps not a promise.

Try something like this:

```
 resolve:
   courseDetails: function () {
      return CourseFactory.getCourseDetails();
   }
```

Make sure getCourseDetails returns a promise.

Comment: Show us the code for courseDetails injected in the controller.

Comment: If this is ALL the code then $scope.courseDetails = courseDetails; results into $scope.courseDetails being undefined because I don;t see courseDetails being defined as any angular service. Try the debugger put a breakpoint at the line above in your controller and see what is the value.

Comment: Or try hardcoding  $scope.courseDetails =  {Id: 1, Name: 'ww'}; for debugging purposes and show us what you get.

Comment: I have debugged the code. $scope.courseDetails gets filled with the required data when the Edit() function is called in the root scope.

Comment: This is what is there in $scope.courseDetails at runtime:  {0: Object
Duration: "2 Months"
Id: 2
Name: "LINQ"}

Comment: {0: Object Duration: "2 Months" Id: 2 Name: "LINQ"} definitely looks invalid JSON.

Comment: You were right. This was the problem. When I converted courseDetails to JSON type, it's working fine.  Thanks!!!